# Are there two norms in any space that neither of them is subordinate to the other?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, theorem-provers

Can you prove if no or give an example if yes?

Obviously, this should be an example of an infinite-dimensional space, since in a finite-dimensional space, any two norms are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the  space $X$ of finitely non-zero sequences let $\|(x_n)\|_1=\sum a_n|x_n|$ and $\|(x_n)\|_2=\sum b_n|x_n|$ where $a_n>0$ and $b_n >0$ for all $n$. These are norms on $X$. Neither is sub-ordinate to the other if neither $\frac {a_n} {b_n}$ nor $\frac {b_n} {a_n}$ is bounded. I will let you construct such sequences.

Detailed solution: 
Take $a_n=1$ for $n$ even and $n$ for $n$ odd, $b_n=n$ for $n$ even and $1$ for $n$ odd. Prove by contradiction that inequalities like $\|.\|_1 \leq C \|.\|_2$ and $\|.\|_2 \leq C \|.\|_1$  cannot hold. If the first inequality holds put $(x_n)=e_n$ to see that $|a_n| \leq C|b_n|$ which is a contradiction. Second case is similar.

Comment: Sequence are not bounded = doesn't have limit?

Comment: Also when you write $|x_n|$ in sum you mean $|x^n_i|$?

Comment: @dasfex I have given a detailed answer.

Comment: @Joe Yes, for sure. Thanks for pointing out.